# Get error putting Admob in Wallpaper settings

Tags: java, android, admob

Sorry, im so new with admob, I put it in another simple apps, but i cant got it in a livewallpaper. I get a com.google.android.gms.ads.adView cannot be cast to android.preference.Preference

This is my livewallpaper_settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:key="livewallpaper_settings"
    android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings" >

    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/livewallpaper_testpattern_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/livewallpaper_testpattern_prefix"
        android:key="livewallpaper_testpattern"
        android:summary="@string/livewallpaper_settings_summary"
        android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings_title" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="livewallpaper_movement"
        android:summary="@string/livewallpaper_movement_summary"
        android:summaryOff="Still test pattern"
        android:summaryOn="Moving test pattern"
        android:title="@string/livewallpaper_movement_title" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

this is my LiveWallpaperSettings.java:

```
package ca.jvsh.livewallpaper;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
public class LiveWallpaperSettings extends PreferenceActivity
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(LiveWallpaper.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.livewallpaper_settings);
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have any types of view other than a Preference in a PreferenceScreen.
An AdView is not a Preference.

And besides are you user's really going to spend all the time in your app on a preference screen?

Comment: Thank you for the info! I dont know.. How I could monetize this kinds of apps? William